# How to Disable Optimization for One File in Xcode

Tags: xcode, clang, llvm

My Xcode project depends on another library, that cause errors in my project when I built it with `[-O3]` option.
The errors are in just one file. So I want to turn off the `[-O3]` option for that file.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the target, look under `Build Phases`. Open the `Compile Sources` step. Locate the file in question, and click the `Compiler flags` column to the right.
Enter `-O0` to turn off optimisation.

Comment: I have tried this, but if I set the [-O3] option in target build settings, this compiler flag for this file seems won't override the [-O3] option.

Comment: Overriding the target build settings is the primary use case of this feature, and it "should work". Have you checked the resulting compiler flags in the build log?

Comment: That's odd, both optimization options exists.

Comment: The compiler should use the last one, and that should be -O0…

Comment: So,my building error should be not solved by this way, I guess.

Comment: Just came here to confirm this does work, even on Xcode 10.1 - and it was a pain in the ass to track down why this particular file was being optimised when the build settings specified `-O0`. Big thanks!

Comment: Trying to override the build flag for a single file in the fashion on Xcode 12.5 does not seem to have any effect (-Onone). Is there any thoughts on why this might be?

Comment: Same issue as @Lkabo here, on 12.5.1 I seem to be unable to properly override it. Both `-O0` and `-Onone` don't work, unless I'm missing something.