# XCode 12.5 w/ MacOS 11.3 - Fails to Archive: Illegal Instruction: 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This question has been asked a few times in the past, but none of those answers seem to match what is currently going on.

I have an app (SwiftUI) that builds, runs, tests fine on simulators and devices. But when attempting to Archive for iOS and/or MacOS, the archiving fails with a vague error "Illegal instruction: 4". The compiler then lists a bunch of files and directories which offer no help.

ERROR MESSAGE SNIPPET:

```
CompileSwift normal arm64 (in target 'App Name' from project 'App Name')
```

...Lists a bunch of directories

```
error: Illegal instruction: 4 (in target 'App Name' from project 'App Name')
```

The weird thing is that prior to the XCode and MacOS update, this app will Archive fine. So I am left to assume something was deprecated in this latest release.

My question is: What are some debugging tools to help me start to find where in my code this may be happening? Why would the app build and run fine on simulators and devices but not Archive? makes no sense to me.

***I did test this by attempting to Archive on another MacBook with MacOS 11.0.1 and XCode 12.2, and it Archives fine.. Although, this is really useless since you cant upload a binary compiled with an older version of XCode..*** *I was able to upload the binary using the older Xcode version, not sure if it will let me release this, but I will try that for now.

I have considered deleting and reinstalling XCode, but I don't know if that would be a waste of time. Maybe something didn't update properly?

At a loss. Any insight is appreciated.

***update***

When I edit the scheme and change Archive from Release to Debug, it Archive's?!

What am I missing?

***2nd update:***

When changing the build settings, under the Project, Swift Compilier, Code Generation, Optimization level from Optimize for Speed -O to No Optimization -Onone, the app Archives with no issues.

Comment: Sounds very much like a compiler or Xcode bug. File a report with Apple. What happens when you change the "Run" scheme to release?

Comment: I will try that in a bit and post the results. Also, will file a bug report. In the meantime, do you think there will be any impact sending an archive built for debug live?

Comment: When building with the Run Config set to Release, the same failure occurs. Bug report submitted to Apple.

Comment: Addtl info discovered, adding to post

Comment: OK definitely a compiler bug in this case. If you can narrow it down to the module or even function level that would likely help gettings this fixed immensely. You might want to file the bug on bugs.swift.org also if you get to a reproducible case.

Comment: I narrowed it down to what is causing the crash. I have an Array of identifiable objects in the app and it has grown to now around 1,100 objects. These objects get loaded into a database on first fun but it would seem that after adding the last 100 or so objects, the compiler is unable to deal with this file. Is there any way that I can exclude this one file from being optimized?

Comment: (DID NOT WORK...): I believe I found the answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353049/how-to-disable-optimization-for-one-file-in-xcode

Comment: work around was to break up and eliminate that file as much as possible. able to archive with optimization again. Submitted the problem file to Apple in a bug report..

Comment: Yeah, the Swift compiler really hates large array and dictionary literals. Because of that, I usually don't ship this kind of data as code, but as e.g. JSON files.